# Integrate one mobile application with other (Android and IOS)

Tags: android, ios, swift3, mobile-application

Is it possible to integrate one mobile application with other mobile application in Android and IOS? 
User have both applications installed on his mobile. He is inside one app and let's assume, he want's to perform some operation on another app and once that operation is done, I should get informed in my first app.

Let's take one simple scenario. I have an app which takes photos. After clicking photo, I should get an option of sharing the same on WhatsApp lets say, which will open a WhatsApp and I select a user/group to share that picture and once it is posted there it should redirect to my app and in my mobile app, that photo should be marked like "Shared on WhatsApp" or some right check.

How could I achieve such type of functionality in Android and IOS both? How 2 mobile app communicate with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iOS:**

Yes. It can be done through **URLSchemes**. In iOS, URLSchemes are a powerful way for inter-app communication. Steps to follow.

**Step 1**

Go into your app's **info.plst** file.

**Step 2**

Add a Row to this and call it **"URL types"**

**Step 3**

Expand the first item in **"URL types"** and add a row called **"URL identifier"**, the value of this string should be the reverse domain for your app e.g. **"com.yourcompany.myapp"**.

**Step 4**

Again, add a row into the first item in **"URL types"** and call it "URL Schemes"

**Step 5**

Inside "URL Schemes" you can use each item as a different url you wish to use, so if you wanted to use **"myapp://"** you would create an item called "myapp".

Another option to use **[Deep Linking](https://www.imore.com/deep-and-back-linking-ios-9-explained)**

**Android:**

I think in Android, you can achieve the same with **Intents**. Please check this link. [Android-Interapp communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Comment: Let me try this option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use deeplinks.

Deeplinks should be first defined by the app that is willing to take up external requests. Once it is defined, you could invoke that deeplink from anywhere (another app, messages, email, etc.,) on the device.

You can refer [this link](https://savvyapps.com/blog/how-to-use-deep-linking-in-your-mobile-app) as an example.